# Why Squid ntlm_auth works only when "cache_effective_group root"

Tags: proxy, squid, ntlm

I have Debian 8 Jessie with Samba configured as AD member server.
Samba+Winbind works perfectly: I can create shares and assign rights for AD users; *getent passwd* shows both local and AD users, etc.

Some additional checks like:

- net testjoin
- klist and klist -k /etc/krb5.keytab
- wbinfo -t
- wbinfo -a mydomain\myuser%mypasswd
- wbinfo -u
- /usr/local/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-basic

all are succeded

Auth config in **squid.conf** (only lines related to question):

```
...
auth_param ntlm program /usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp
auth_param ntlm children 16 startup=5 idle=5
...
acl AuthorizedUsers proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow AuthorizedUsers
http_access deny all
...
```

I also added user **proxy** to **winbindd_priv** group ([as mentioned here](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Ntlm#winbind_privileged_pipe_permissions)):

```
gpasswd -a proxy winbindd_priv
```

After restart Squid I get dialog asking username and password in browser (any browser).

When I set

```
cache_effective_group root
```

ntlm_auth works fine: no username and password dialog boxes, username is got automatically and displayed in **access.log**.
Auth does not work when I remove *cache_effective_group*.
It seems like *ntlm_auth* cannot connect to Winbind via privileged pipe when effective group *is not root*.

I tried some:

1. change group ownership of **/var/run/samba/winbind_privileged** to **proxy**
2. change permission of **/var/run/samba/winbind_privileged** to allow access to any user
3. set **cache_effective_group** explicitly to **winbindd_priv** (and check it in process list)
4. completely change group membership of **proxy** user to **winbindd_priv**

Nothing helped

Only "cache_effective_group root" helps

That is not a good idea for me to use root group for Squid.

What to check else to run it as unprivileged user?

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer by myself:

The real place for Winbind privileged pipe is **/var/lib/samba/winbindd_privileged** (*NOT /var/run/samba/winbind_privileged*)

In Jessie it owned by *root:root* and has rights: *0750*

I've changed ownership:

```
chown root:winbindd_priv /var/lib/samba/winbindd_privileged/
```

Now everything works fine without "cache_effective_group"

PS. Finally there is a bug reported in 2014 :) 
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=754339 that has not been fixed yet

Answer (score 0):

Been fighting an issue with ntlm auth on Ubuntu 16 with squid 3. This was my exact issue. As soon as I changed the ownership ntlm auth started working immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved using sg on **`squid.conf`**

```
auth_param ntlm program /usr/bin/sg winbindd_priv -c "/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --diagnostics --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp --require-membership-of=MYDOMAINNAME+WEBGROUPS"
```